# Android MediaPlayer, how can I pass it an InputStream as datasource?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, inputstream

To Android's [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer) I want to pass an InputStream as data source. However its methods don't accept it. Can I convert the InputStream to a format acceptable by the setDataSource Methods and if so, how?

Comment: Do you mean an url for audio source?

Comment: I know how to use a URL but I specifically want to do this with an input stream

Comment: Have you tried creating a MediaDataSource wrapper for your InputStream?  Though this is API 23+.  Looks like MediaPlayer needs random access to the stream, i.e. the ability to seek and read at any location.